# Notation of differential equations

Tags: derivatives, notation

I have just started a course on differential equations, and unfortunetely enough for me, we immediately used notation foreign for me, for example:

$$ x^2 \left(\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)^2 = \sin( x)\;\textrm{ and}\;\; y \times \dfrac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = \sin(x)$$ were used as examples of non-linear ordinary differential equations. My questions are

- Is $\large \frac{dy}{dx}$ equal to $y'$? Also, what then is $\large\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}\;$? 
  I have looked up the formal mathematical definition but it somewhat confuses me,
- Why on earth is this notation used, instead of just using $\;'\;$ or $\;''\;$? It seems to me much more confusing and unnecessarily messy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation is correct: $$\frac{dy}{dx} = y' \;\text{ and likewise,}\;\;\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = y''$$

It's often simpler to use $y'$, I agree. But there are contexts, for example in implicit differentiation, or when $x$ and $y$ are defined in terms of a parameter, like $t$, in which using $\frac{dy}{dx}$, e.g., makes explicit that we want to differentiate $y$ with respect to $x$. There are other advantages, but when no confusion or ambiguity results from using $y'$ to denote $\frac{dy}{dx}$, by all means, use it!

Please also see the previous thread [Why the second derivative is written as $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25102/why-is-the-2nd-derivative-written-as-frac-mathrm-d2y-mathrm-dx2) for more comprehensive information as to what exactly the notation denotes, and its origin.

Comment: Thank you. One final question; Why is $\dfrac{d^2 y}{dx^2}$ equal to $y''$?

Comment: It simply denoting the second derivative of y which respect to x, where you differentiate with respect to $x$ each time (twice). I do agree that the notation and placement of the "exponent" is confusing. I don't know if that clarifies anything!

Comment: It still is somewhat fussy but I don't think it matters too much; I assume if you want the n-th derivative it just becomes $\dfrac{d^n y}{dx^n}$?

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you!