# Notation of the second derivative - Where does the $d$ go?

Tags: derivatives, notation

In school, I was taught that we use $\dfrac{du}{dx}$ as a notation for the first derivative of a function $u(x)$. I was also told that we could use the $d$ just like any variable.

After some time we were given the notation for the second derivative and it was explained as follows:

$$
\frac{d\left(\frac{du}{dx}\right)}{dx} = \frac{d^2 u}{dx^2}
$$

What I do not get here is, if we can use the $d$ as any variable, I would get the following result:

$$
\frac{d\left(\frac{du}{dx}\right)}{dx} =\frac{ddu}{dx\,dx} = \frac{d^2 u}{d^2 x^2}
$$

Apparently, it is not the same as the notation we were given. A $d$ is missing.

I have done some research on this and found some vague comments about "There are reasons for that, but you do not need to know..." or "That is mainly a  notation issue, but you do not need to know further."

**So what I am asking for is:** Is this really just a notation thing?
If so, does this mean we can actually NOT use d like a variable?
If not, where does the $d$ go?

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477507/is-d2y-dx-a-valid-mathematical-notation/477523) related question, but it does not really answer my specific question. So I would not see it as a duplicate, but correct me if my search has not been sufficient and there indeed is a similar question out there already.

Comment: $d$ is not a variable; in other words $dxdx$ is not $d$ times $x$ times $d$ times $x$.  At best, you can think of $dx$ as one object (with a two letter name), an infinitesimal.

Comment: $d$ cannot be used just like any variable. Otherwise you will have $du/dx=u/x$ for example.

Comment: I have a hard time to believe somebody told you this. Maybe they said it about the entity "$dx$"

Comment: It's because the `dx` is "in parentheses", so to speak.

Comment: I kinda assumed $dx^2$ meant $(dx)^2$; i.e. $dx$ is basically one variable.

Comment: I asked about the origin of this notation on https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3323/who-invented-the-leibnitz-notation-fracd2ydx2-for-the-second-derivati.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist I don't think I've seen a multivariable calculus book that does that. I've only seen books write things like $\partial x\partial y$ in the denominator, and I believe for good reason.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist First, it destroys the nice "multiplication" of factors of the form $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ by saying something like "$\partial\partial=\partial^2$ on top, but $(\partial x)(\partial y)=\partial xy$ on bottom". More importantly, IMO, is the fact that, in general: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ don't commute, but $x$ and $y$ do. So to use the notation you proposed would require that $\partial xy$ in a denominator can't be replaced with $\partial yx$, even though in all other real-anaylsis contexts $xy\to yx$ would be fine.

Comment: @MarkS. Fair point; By Clairaut's Theorem reversing the order of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ is valid for many functions, but definitely not always.

Comment: You really can't use $d$ as a variable; however, you *can* use $dx$ as a variable.  (This works well when doing, for example, integration by substitution.)  Possibly this is what you were told (or what they meant to tell you.)

Comment: Mistake is that $d(du)=d(\frac{du}{dx})$ is false. I wrote a some answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477507/is-d2y-dx-a-valid-mathematical-notation/4830775#4830775 which can be useful also here.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> where does the $d$ go?

Physicist checking in. All the other answers seem to focus on whether $d$ is a variable and are neglecting the heart of your question.

Simply put, $dx$ is the name of one thing, so in your example

$$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}=\frac{d^2u}{\left(dx\right)^2}$$

In your words, the "second $d$" is inside the implied parentheses.

Comment: +1.  I'm surprised that so many other answers missed this aspect of the question.

Comment: I guess the same could occur with a delta, for example with the formula $U=\frac12 k \Delta x^2$ one might interpret it as $U=\frac12 k (\Delta x)^2$ (the elastic potential energy in a Hooke spring).

Comment: Thanks for this short but good answer. Using the $dx$ as one unit and not as two separate things $d$ and $x$ clears the things up a lot.

Comment: Gotta love physicists.

Comment: The problem is that if dx is meant to be a single symbol, then I'll start to doubt the meaning of lots and lots of other symbols. Which ones are one and which ones are two?

Answer (score 43):

Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz, who introduced this notation in the 17th century, intended $dx$ to be an infinitely small change in $x$ and $du$ to be the corresponding infinitely small change in $u$, so that if, for example, $du/dx=3$ at a particular point that means $u$ is changing $3$ times as fast as $x$ is changing at that point.

The notation $\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}$ actually means $\dfrac{d\left(\dfrac{du}{dx}\right)}{dx}$, the infinitely small change in $du/dx$ divided by the corresponding infinitely small change in $x$.  Thus the second derivative is the rate of change of the rate of change.

Notice that if $u$ is in meters and $x$ in seconds, then $du/dx$ is in $\dfrac{\text{m}}{\text{sec}}$, i.e. meters per second, and $d^2 u/dx^2$ is in $\dfrac{\text{m}}{\text{sec}^2}$, i.e. meters per second per second.  Thus $dx^2$ means $(dx)^2$, so the units of measurement of $x$ get squared, and $d^2y$ is in the same units of measurement that $y$ is in, consistently with the fact that $y$ is not a part of what gets squared in the numerator.

Comment: Now I think of it, using $dx^2$ instead of $(dx)^2$ does not seem strange given that we write $\mathrm{cm}^2$ rather than $(\mathrm{cm})^2$.

Answer (score 37):

$d$ is not a variable, and neither is $dx$ for that matter.

It is confusing because in some case, like the chain rule, differentials *act* like variables which can cancel:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dt}$$

However, it is most appropriate to think of $\frac{d}{dx}$ as an *operator* that does something.

Thus, $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{d}{dx} y)=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}y$.

Somewhat similarly, you wouldn't say that $\sin^2 x=s^2i^2n^2x$

Edit: In case it isn't from the example, you cannot separate $dx$. That is, $dx$ is not $d$ times $x$. This is very much analogous to chemistry when we say things like $\Delta H$. This isn't $\Delta$ times $H$. It is $\Delta$ (change) *of* $H$.

Comment: Are you sure this is a good example? I wouldn't say $\sin^2 x = (\sin x)^2$ either, if I didn't know that's the conventional meaning. What I would rather say is $\sin x^2 = (\sin x)^2$, which is _not_ commonly understood so.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I agree. I would more likely mistake $\sin^2 x$ to mean $\sin(\sin(x))$, which would actually be similar to the reasoning for $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{d}{dx}y) = \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2(y)=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}y$. And of course the issue with $\sin x ^ 2 = (\sin x)^2 $ is that it could easily be mistaken for $\sin\left(x^2\right)$

Comment: @leftaroundabout I don't see how somebody who didn't know what $\sin^2 x$ means could reasonably come to the conclusion taht it would mean $\sin(x^2)$. The "squared" is applied to the sine, so it could only reasonably mean "take the sine of $x$ and then square it" or "take the sine of $x$ twice (i.e., $\sin(\sin x)$."

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I didn't say anything about $\sin(x^2)$. In fact that was the point of my comment: it _would_, analogously to $\mathrm{d}x^2 \equiv (\mathrm{d}x)^2$, make some sense to have the convention $\sin\! x^2 \equiv (\sin x)^2$, i.e. to parse the function application tighter than exponentiation. However, what's actually done is a weirder convention, namely $\sin^2 x \equiv (\sin x)^2$.

Comment: -1 This answer doesn't seem to address the main issue of the question ("A $d$ is missing.") at all. The OP seems to think that $dx^2$ means $d(x^2)$, not $(dx)^2$, so I don't see how he could agree with the notation $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dx} = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ used here without explanation.

Comment: Ok; I added another line in case it was still ambiguous. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 8):

${\rm d}(A)$ means an *infinitesimally* small change in $A$. The ${\rm d}$ is an operator and you better look at it as a function and not a value.

If anything we drop the parenthesis from ${\rm d}x$ for brevity as it should be ${\rm d}(x)$ as in $$\frac{{\rm d}(y)}{{\rm d}(x)}$$ and
$$\frac{{\rm d}(\frac{{\rm d}(y)}{{\rm d}(x)})}{{\rm d}(x)} = \frac{ \frac{1}{{\rm d}(x)} {\rm d}({\rm d}(y))}{{\rm d}(x)} = \frac{{\rm d}({\rm d}(y))}{({\rm d}(x))^2} = \frac{{\rm d}^2(y)}{({\rm d}x)^2} = \frac{{\rm d}^2 y}{{\rm d}x^2}$$

Comment: The derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is not the ratio of a small change of $y$ to a small change in $x$.  Even in nonstandard analysis it's not defined that simply.

Comment: Actually it is $$ \frac{{\rm d}A}{{\rm d}x} =  \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{ \left(A(x+h) - A(x)\right)}{\left( (x+h)-x \right)} $$ This is the _definition_ of a derivative (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative).

Comment: I'm well aware but your answer makes it seem like $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d(y)}{d(x)}$ where you define $d(y)$ as a "small change in $y$" and likewise for $d(x)$.  To be clearer, your answer makes it seem like $$\frac{dA}{dx} = \frac{A(x+h)-A(x)}{((x+h)-x)}$$ **without the limiting process**!

Comment: Ok, I added the word "infinitesimally" to the answer. Happy now? The point of the answer is to view the ${\rm d}(\square)$ as an operator.

Comment: There are several contexts in which $d$ should be considered an operator -- chief among them being as the exterior derivative of a differential $k$-form -- but IMO the derivative in scalar calculus is not one of them.  An "infinitesimally small number" not equal to zero doesn't exist in $\Bbb R$.  This is fine as a "heuristic" but the claim that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ actually **is** a ratio -- whether of infinitesimals or finite differences -- is just not true.

Comment: A value can be infinitesimally small without being zero, the same way the `Dirac` function can be infinite but evaluate to a finite value over an integral. So the result of ${\rm d}(A)$ exists in $\Bbb R$ although undefined. I think you imply that ${\rm d}x \equiv 0$ whereas I imply that ${\rm d}x \neq 0$

Comment: That's false.  Such a quantity would violate the [Archmedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) of the real numbers.  You have to extend the reals to the hyperreals to make use of nonzero infinitesimals.  [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_calculus#Definition_of_derivative) is the closest formalization of what you're talking about that exists in mathematics and it still doesn't define the derivative as a fraction of infinitesimals, but as the **standard part** of a fraction of infinitesimals.  Note that is not a part of standard analysis.

Comment: Also the formalization of the Dirac "function" is as a distribution or a measure -- i.e. something that only makes sense under an integral sign.  It's not a function which evaluates to infinity at $x=0$ -- that's just the picture that we give students so that they have some way to visualize it.

Comment: Arguments about axiomatisation aside, this answer is the best intuitive answer to "where does the d go?", in my opinion. If you wanted to make it precise, you could simply say that $df$ is defined as $f(x+h)-f(x)$, and then have an implicit convention that we always take the $h\to 0$ limit whenever we write down an expression involving $d$.

Comment: @Bye_World: There are places for squeemish nonsense and this one isn't one of them. $dy/dx$ might not be 'formally' a ratio, but it is BY DEFINITION indiscernable from a finite, well-defined ratio - you give me a desired level of precision and I will give you a ratio that is, up to precision, identical to $dy/dx$ at the given point. "This is intuitionists physics, not real math!!!!" you cry. But obviously, this is exactly what we're doing when we are taking limits.

Answer (score 5):

Think of the meaning of $d/dx$. The $d$ in the numerator is an operator: it says, "take the infinitesimal difference of whatever follows $d/dx$". In contrast, the $dx$ in the denominator is just a number (yes, I know; mathematicians, please don't cringe): it is the infinitesimal difference in $x$.

So $d/dx$ means "take the infinitesimal difference of whatever follows, and then divide by the number $dx$."

Similarly, $d^2/dx^2$ means "take the infinitesimal difference of the infinitesimal difference of whatever follows, and then divide by the square of the number $dx$."

In short, the $d$ in the numerator is an operator, whereas in the denominator, it is part of a symbol. A slightly less ambiguous notation, as suggested by user1717828, would be to put the $(dx)$ in the denominator in parenthesis, but it really isn't necessary in practice.