# Second derivative symbol $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$!

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm currently studying taking the second derivative of equations and I have been told the symbol used to represent second derivative is

> $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$

I was just wondering, why this symbol is chosen? Why is it not $$\frac{dy^2}{dx^2}$$ or $$\frac{d^2y}{d^2x}$$

Comment: Caution, $dy^2/dx^2$ can very well be interpreted as $(dy/dx)^2$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ has differ from $(\dfrac{dy}{dx})^2$.

Comment: @user108128: I know, why do you tell me ?

Comment: See my answer on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475016/leibniz-notation-for-high-order-derivatives/4831211#4831211

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first derivation is
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}$$
taking other derivation respect to $x$ has the representation $\dfrac{d}{dx}$, then for second derivative we write
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)=\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$
means in non-standard symbol 
$$\color{blue}{\dfrac{d\times d~y}{(dx)^2}}$$

Answer (score 5):

Differentiation by $x$ takes $y$ to
$$\frac{dy}{dx}$$
or if you like, to
$$\frac{d}{dx}y.$$
One would write, say
$$\frac{d}{dx}\cos x=-\sin x$$
etc.

So the derivative of $dy/dx$ is then
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dx}$$
which one naturally abbreviates as
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

If you think of the first derivative $g=\frac{df}{dx}$ as a function you would like to differentiate, the result should have the symbol $\frac{dg}{dx}=\frac{d\frac{df}{dx}}{dx}$. The latter is naively "computed" to be $\frac{d^2f}{(dx)^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$d^2y$ expresses that we have an (infinitesimal) second order difference, the difference of a difference, while $dx^2$ is indeed the square of an (infinitesimal) first order.

Might have been clearer to write $\dfrac{d_2y}{dx^2}$ instead.

Answer (score 2):

$$ y'=\frac {d}{dx}(y)=\frac {dy}{dx} $$

$$ y''=\frac {d}{dx}(\frac{d}{dx}y)=\frac {d^2y}{dx^2} $$
$$ y'''=\frac {d}{dx}(\frac {d^2}{dx^2}(y))=\frac {d^3y}{dx^3}$$