# Given $dy/dx=-x/y$, how can I solve $d^2 y / dx^2$

Tags: derivatives

The part that confuses me is the square being next to the $d$ vs being to the variable. My intuition tells me $d^2x$ is equivalent to $(dx)^2$ and $dx^2$ should be $d(x^2)$ (if that notation is valid)

Comment: $d^{2}y/dx^{2}$ is just the second derivative. So, it is the derivative of $dy/dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac xy \\ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{y\cdot(-1)-(-x)\frac{dy}{dx}}{y^2}=\frac{-y+x\cdot -\frac xy}{y^2} =\frac{-y^2-x^2}{y^3}$$ Note that $d^2x \ne (dx)^2 \ne d(x^2) $, it is just a fancy way to say that we are taking the derivative *of* the derivative.

Comment: Oh, what a confusing notation. Is there any reason it is written like that?

Comment: @user1754322 Not that I know of. Maybe you’d like to ask the person who invented this himself.

Comment: Just found it https://math.stackexchange.com/q/475016/153526

Answer (score 0):

It is:
$$y''=(y')'=-\frac1y+\frac{x}{y^2}y'=-\frac1y-\frac{x^2}{y^3}.$$